# How to enter more data than a screen to an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner at Android Studio and, for example, I want to make 30 buttons on a vertical `Linear Layout` or I have a very long text. How can I display it all in one screen? I mean how can I make it scrollable ?

Comment: Scrollview with a LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes. It is possible, isn't it ? Anyways, it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

add the buttons you want the view will scroll

Comment: The buttons were just an example. I actually want to put there some text, a recycler view , text again and another recycler view. That's what I need scroll view for. I tried it using inside a Relative Layout and it didn't work.